# UWP update UI control from a task running in a different thread

Tags: multithreading, uwp

UI has a label named lblMyLabel.
It’s bound to a view model MyViewModel.

A task is running on a different thread which pulls message from a service.( for example)

When a this task receives a specific value it should update the UI label with it.

I always get a error that it was Marshalled in a different thread .

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update UI,you should run on the UI's dispatcher thread.You can call `Dispatcher.RunAsync` to back onto the UI's dispatcher thread.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Start a Task
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        { 
        }
        //Back onto the UI thread
        var a = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            //Update UI
            MyTextBlock.Text = "Update";
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Faywang for your response. I am new to UWP. Is it possible for you to provide a full example of the dispatcher.

Comment: You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) to learn more about it.I have updated my answer.I start a Task and back onto the UI thread when I want to update the textblock.